# Followup questions: Using Maven to only sign and deploy jars to Maven Central. Build and compilation is done entirely with Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant

See followup question: *[Followup part 2 -- Using Maven to only sign and deploy jars to Maven Central. Build and compilation is done entirely with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793800/followup-2-using-maven-to-only-sign-and-deploy-jars-to-maven-central-build-a)*

This is a follow up to this question: *[How to use Maven to only sign three jars and push them to Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771467/how-to-use-maven-to-only-sign-three-jars-and-push-them-to-maven-central)*

---

My goal here is to have Maven sign and push the *already created* jars to Maven Central. The [three jars](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html#supply-javadoc-and-sources)

- `xbnjava-0.1.2.jar`
- `xbnjava-0.1.2-sources.jar`
- `xbnjava-0.1.2-javadoc.jar`

are located in `R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.1\download`

These jars are created independently, by my Ant build process. Maven is not used for building or compiling my project in any way--I'm only using it to put the jars on Maven Central. (With [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24772950/2736496) in my previous question, it seems the signing portion of my POM is at least a lot closer to what it needs to be.)

When executing `mvn deploy`, I'm getting the error `Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized`. Maven is not asking me for my key-passphrase, which I expect it should, and I don't see where this information (the location of my saved key?) is configured. (Signing files is new to me, so please forgive any incorrect terminology).

(Also, the project's `groupId` is `com.github.xbn`, but there is no `xbn` directory in

[`https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/`](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/)

I've opened a support ticket on sonatype regarding this, although I don't know if it's part of the problem or not.)

Diagnostic information is below. If anyone can provide guidance, I really need it. Thank you.

---

Here is my `pom.xml`, which is located in

`R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava\pom.xml`

(Notice the jars are in a the `build` directory, not the sandbox.)

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.github.xbn</groupId>
       <artifactId>xbnjava</artifactId>
       <packaging>pom</packaging>
       <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <name>XBN-Java</name>
       <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava</url>
       <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
       <organization>
          <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
       </organization>
       <description>XBN-Java is a collection of generically-useful backend (server side, non-GUI) programming utilities, featuring RegexReplacer and FilteredLineIterator. XBN-Java is the foundation of Codelet (http://codelet.aliteralmind.com).</description>

       <parent>
          <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
          <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
          <version>7</version>
       </parent>

       <licenses>
          <license>
             <name>Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3.0</name>
             <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt</url>
          </license>
          <license>
             <name>Apache Software License (ASL) version 2.0</name>
             <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
          </license>
       </licenses>

       <developers>
          <developer>
             <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
             <email>aliteralmind-github@yahoo.com</email>
             <roles>
                <role>Lead Developer</role>
             </roles>
          </developer>
       </developers>

       <issueManagement>
          <system>GitHub Issue Tracker</system>
          <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava/issues</url>
       </issueManagement>

       <distributionManagement>
          <snapshotRepository>
             <id>ossrh</id>
             <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
          </snapshotRepository>
       </distributionManagement>

       <scm>
          <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</connection>
          <url>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</url>
          <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</developerConnection>
       </scm>

       <properties>
          <java.version>1.7</java.version>
          <jarprefix>../build/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/download/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</jarprefix>
       </properties>

       <profiles>
          <!--
          This profile will sign the JAR file, sources file, and javadocs file using the GPG key on the local machine.
          See: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/How+To+Generate+PGP+Signatures+With+Maven
          -->
          <profile>
             <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
             <activation>
                <property>
                   <name>release</name>
                   <value>true</value>
                </property>
             </activation>
             <build>
                <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                      <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>1.8</version>
                      <executions>
                         <execution>
                            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                               <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                               <artifacts>
                                  <artifact>
                                     <file>${jarprefix}.jar</file>
                                     <type>jar</type>
                                  </artifact>
                                  <artifact>
                                     <file>${jarprefix}-javadoc.jar</file>
                                     <type>jar</type>
                                     <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                                  </artifact>
                                  <artifact>
                                     <file>${jarprefix}-sources.jar</file>
                                     <type>jar</type>
                                     <classifier>sources</classifier>
                                  </artifact>
                               </artifacts>
                            </configuration>
                         </execution>
                      </executions>
                   </plugin>
                </plugins>
             </build>
          </profile>
       </profiles>
</project>
```

My `settings.xml`, which is located in

`C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.2.2\conf\settings.xml`

(The `M2_HOME` environment variable is set to `C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.2.2`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <servers>
      <server>
         <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
         <username>aliteralmind</username>
         <password>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_PASSWORD </password>
      </server>
      <server>
         <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
         <username>aliteralmind</username>
         <password>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_PASSWORD </password>
      </server>
   </servers>

   <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
   <proxies></proxies>
   <mirrors></mirrors>
   <profiles></profiles>
</settings>
```

### Here is the output from calling `mvn deploy`

```
[R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava]mvn deploy > temp.txt
TCC: C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\mvn.bat [182]  Missing SETLOCAL

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava\pom.xml to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\xbn\xbnjava\0.1.2-SNAPSHOT\xbnjava-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ xbnjava ---
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.150828-1.pom
2/4 KB
4/4 KB
```

(the failure portion:)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.407 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-16T11:08:29-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xbnjava: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.xbn:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2-20140716.150828-1 from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.150828-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

---

### And again, this time using `mvn deploy -e`

```
[R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava]mvn deploy -e >temp.txt
TCC: C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\mvn.bat [182]  Missing SETLOCAL

[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava\pom.xml to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\xbn\xbnjava\0.1.2-SNAPSHOT\xbnjava-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ xbnjava ---
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.142845-1.pom
2/4 KB
4/4 KB
```

(the failure portion:)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.357 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-16T10:28:45-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xbnjava: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.xbn:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2-20140716.142845-1 from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.142845-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xbnjava: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.xbn:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2-20140716.142845-1 from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.142845-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.xbn:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2-20140716.142845-1 from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.142845-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
  ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.xbn:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2-20140716.142845-1 from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.142845-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
  at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:149)
  ... 21 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.xbn:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2-20140716.142845-1 from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.142845-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:337)
  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:268)
  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
  at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
  ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.github.xbn:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2-20140716.142845-1 from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.142845-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
  at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1016)
  at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
  at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:895)
  at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:522)
  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:331)
  ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/xbn/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.142845-1.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
  at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:573)
  at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:493)
  at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:474)
  at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:454)
  at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:871)
  ... 28 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Make sure the server id in the settings.xml corresponds to the id in your dependency management section. Otherwise Maven does not know how to find credentials.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, there's an updated guide to [deploying to Maven central with Ant](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-ant.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your settings.xml file configuration is the problem cause your Id's in your server configurations do not correspond with the entries in distributionManagement:

```xml
<distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

You have to use the following server id's:

```xml
<server>
  <id>ossrh</id>
  <username>username</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
```

They have to correspond with the entries in distributionManagement.

Comment: That seems to be it. I can't honestly say it "works" yet, but because of this, and the fact that I was using the wrong `groupId` (which was corrected by sonatype support), for the first time, calling `mvn deploy` did *not* end in error. (The files seem to have uploaded, although I still don't see them on a Maven Central search...will likely post a followup question.) Thank you, to both you and @AlexeyGavrilov for the help. Maven has been nothing but frustration.

Comment: Followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793800/followup-2-using-maven-to-only-sign-and-deploy-jars-to-maven-central-build-a