# Followup part 2 -- Using Maven to only sign and deploy jars to Maven Central. Build and compilation is done entirely with Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant

*This is a follow up to:* ***[Followup questions: Using Maven to only sign and deploy jars to Maven Central. Build and compilation is done entirely with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784749/followup-questions-using-maven-to-only-sign-and-deploy-jars-to-maven-central-b)***

---

Thanks to the answer to the previous questions, and some advice from a sonatype support person, I've just had my first "non failure". Here's the current output for `mvn deploy`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava\pom.xml to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.2-SNAPSHOT\xbnjava-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ xbnjava ---
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
607/607 B
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (607 B at 0.5 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140717.010135-5.pom
2/4 KB
4/4 KB
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140717.010135-5.pom (4 KB at 11.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml
290/290 B
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml (290 B at 1.5 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
607/607 B
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (607 B at 2.5 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml
290/290 B
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml (290 B at 1.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.579 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-16T21:01:36-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

According to this log, the following files were uploaded into

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava

- `maven-metadata.xml`
- `0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml`
- `0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140717.010135-5.pom`

When actually looking at that directory in my browser, I see these files:

- `maven-metadata.xml` (all files also have a `md5` and `sha1` version)
- `0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml`
- `0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.174151-1.pom`

So, I don't understand why the log says the `20140717` files were sent, but the server actually contains the `20140716` versions. But there's a bigger problem, as the goal is to have

- `xbnjava-0.1.2.jar`
- `xbnjava-0.1.2-sources.jar`
- `xbnjava-0.1.2-javadoc.jar`

on the server (along with their `*.asc` companions) and none of them are.

In the POM, I have this property

```
<properties>
   <jarprefix>../build/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/download/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</jarprefix>
</properties>
```

and this `plugins` block (which is a subset of the `profiles` section), which contains three artifacts, each of which explicitly points to one of those three jar files

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <artifacts>
                  <artifact>
                     <file>${jarprefix}.jar</file>
                     <type>jar</type>
                  </artifact>
                  <artifact>
                     <file>${jarprefix}-javadoc.jar</file>
                     <type>jar</type>
                     <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                  </artifact>
                  <artifact>
                     <file>${jarprefix}-sources.jar</file>
                     <type>jar</type>
                     <classifier>sources</classifier>
                  </artifact>
               </artifacts>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

(The POM is

```
R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava\pom.xml
```

the jars are in

```
R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.1\download
```

)

So what is the next step in getting the POM to

1. recognize the jar files
2. sign them (and prompt me for my public-key passphrase, right?), and
3. push them to Maven?

Below are my updated `settings.xml` and `pom.xml`.

(The sonatype support person also suggested considering a ["minimal Maven" idea](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/manual-staging-bundle-creation-and-deployment.html), which avoids the POM entirely. It's an intriguing idea, but I'd like to first see this through.)

Thank you for helping me.

---

---

---

Settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <servers>
      <server>
         <id>ossrh</id>
         <username>aliteralmind</username>
         <password>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_PASSWORD</password>
      </server>
   </servers>
   <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
   <proxies></proxies>
   <mirrors></mirrors>
   <profiles></profiles>
</settings>
```

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.github.aliteralmind</groupId>
   <artifactId>xbnjava</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>XBN-Java</name>
   <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava</url>
   <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
   <organization>
      <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
   </organization>
   <description>XBN-Java is a collection of generically-useful backend (server side, non-GUI) programming utilities, featuring RegexReplacer and FilteredLineIterator. XBN-Java is the foundation of Codelet (http://codelet.aliteralmind.com).</description>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
      <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
      <version>7</version>
   </parent>

   <licenses>
      <license>
         <name>Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3.0</name>
         <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt</url>
      </license>
      <license>
         <name>Apache Software License (ASL) version 2.0</name>
         <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      </license>
   </licenses>

   <developers>
      <developer>
         <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
         <email>aliteralmind-github@yahoo.com</email>
         <roles>
            <role>Lead Developer</role>
         </roles>
      </developer>
   </developers>

   <issueManagement>
      <system>GitHub Issue Tracker</system>
      <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava/issues</url>
   </issueManagement>

   <distributionManagement>
      <snapshotRepository>
         <id>ossrh</id>
         <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
   </distributionManagement>

   <scm>
      <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</connection>
      <url>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</url>
      <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</developerConnection>
   </scm>

   <properties>
      <java.version>1.7</java.version>
      <jarprefix>../build/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/download/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</jarprefix>
   </properties>

   <profiles>
      <!--
      This profile will sign the JAR file, sources file, and javadocs file using the GPG key on the local machine.
      See: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/How+To+Generate+PGP+Signatures+With+Maven
      -->
      <profile>
         <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>release</name>
               <value>true</value>
            </property>
         </activation>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.8</version>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <artifacts>
                              <artifact>
                                 <file>${jarprefix}.jar</file>
                                 <type>jar</type>
                              </artifact>
                              <artifact>
                                 <file>${jarprefix}-javadoc.jar</file>
                                 <type>jar</type>
                                 <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                              </artifact>
                              <artifact>
                                 <file>${jarprefix}-sources.jar</file>
                                 <type>jar</type>
                                 <classifier>sources</classifier>
                              </artifact>
                           </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: 1. for the "20140717" problem, are you in the same timezone w/ the server? 2. did you try w/ another computer to see if the dependency can be downloaded?

Comment: @coolcfan Not ready to answer this yet, as I'm not yet uploading the files that I'm expecting (irrespective of date/time)...

Comment: @coolcfan Actually, it seems they're there now: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching the artifacts in the `release-sign-artifacts` profile which was probably disabled when you run the ´mvn deploy´ command. Try running `mvn deploy -Drelease=true` or just move the `release-sign-artifacts` profile to the main .pom section. Not sure you need a separate profile at all.

The timestamps are fine. This is how the Maven repository stores SNAPSHOTs.

Maven has a steep learning curve but once you understand the essential concepts it just works.

Comment: This is it. Excellent. I'm about to write an answer that summarizes what I did. Now onto the next issue...

Answer (score 1):

This is the change I made, as suggested in [@AlexeyGavrilov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24796508/2736496):

Original:

```
<profiles>
   <!--
   This profile will sign the JAR file, sources file, and javadocs file using the GPG key on the local machine.
   See: http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-generate-pgp-signatures-with-maven/
   -->
   <profile>
      <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
      <activation>
         <property>
            <name>release</name>
            <value>true</value>
         </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.8</version>
               <executions>
                  <execution>
                     <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                     <phase>package</phase>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                           <artifact>
                              <file>${jarprefix}.jar</file>
                              <type>jar</type>
                           </artifact>
                           <artifact>
                              <file>${jarprefix}-javadoc.jar</file>
                              <type>jar</type>
                              <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                           </artifact>
                           <artifact>
                              <file>${jarprefix}-sources.jar</file>
                              <type>jar</type>
                              <classifier>sources</classifier>
                           </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                     </configuration>
                  </execution>
               </executions>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

New:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.8</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>attach-artifacts</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                     <artifact>
                        <file>${jarprefix}.jar</file>
                        <type>jar</type>
                     </artifact>
                     <artifact>
                        <file>${jarprefix}-javadoc.jar</file>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                     </artifact>
                     <artifact>
                        <file>${jarprefix}-sources.jar</file>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <classifier>sources</classifier>
                     </artifact>
                  </artifacts>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
   <!--
   This profile will sign the JAR file, sources file, and javadocs file using the GPG key on the local machine.
   See: http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-generate-pgp-signatures-with-maven/
   -->
   <profile>
      <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
      <activation>
         <property>
            <name>release</name>
            <value>true</value>
         </property>
      </activation>
   </profile>
```