# Can't figure out a global setting for pom.xml

Tags: maven

I'm trying to compile an [open source project on Github](https://github.com/SBPrime/AsyncWorldEdit/) that has no build instructions. I know it's built with Maven, but there are some variables that need to be set in settings.xml and I cannot find in the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) anything about the custom variables (outside of "servers", "proxies", etc). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941625/1046013) that helps a bit, but I still cannot figure it out.

For example, Where do I set the value `${global.awe.version}` used in the top level `pom.xml` file, where it seems to be defined 2 lines later:
 `<global.awe.version>3.6.0-rc-05</global.awe.version>`?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ...
    <version>${global.awe.version}</version>
    <properties>        
        <global.awe.version>3.6.0-rc-05</global.awe.version>
        <global.awe-api.version>2.2.0-rc-05</global.awe-api.version>
    </properties>
    ...
```

Comment: the property shoud be set in the pom or any parent pom at project-properties or project-profiles-profile-properties, why do you think that the property should be set in settings.xml ?

Comment: Because the pom.xml doesn't contain any of these variables and it looks like the same variable type as settings.xml

Comment: But in your example was set in property tag, was set as property to use in modules poms