# What repositories do you put in a generic pom file?

Tags: maven-2, repository, pom.xml

I am building a generic parent pom file for my projects.

In that file, I would like to have a list of most common Maven repositories, in order to have most dependencies available in the sub-projects (Jboss, Spring, etc.).

Here is this current pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.courtine</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Parent</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Common repositories</description>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>javanet</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>google</id>
            <name>Google repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>JBoss repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Library Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Library Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

1. Is such a generic file listing common repositories a good idea?
2. Do you know other common public Maven repositories to put in such a generic pom file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to put repositories into a pom. Better use a Repository Manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sontatype.org), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/community.php) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/).
In such kind of pom you should put things like default plugins with their appropriate revisions (pluginManagement) or dependencies which should be used (dependencyManagement).

Take a look for explanation into [this](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/). and take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225535/where-is-the-best-place-to-specify-maven-repositories-pom-xml-or-settings-xml) how to setup this.

Comment: I also use a private Nexus repository.Before, I put theses repositories in settings.xml, but the projects were not portable without this file. Putting the repositories in a parent pom makes my project portable.

Note: I also put in the parent file common dependencies and plugins but it is not the current question.

Comment: your explanation about "Putting the repositories in a parent pom makes my project portable" is not fully true, cause if i got your project it will not work in the environment i am, cause it will fail, cause access to outside only via proxy...so i have to change all pom's which using the parent pom. So the configuration via settings.xml (mirror) + a repo manager will simplify the life...

Answer (score 3):

I have another option for doing what you want to do. You could using a profile in your `settings.xml` which reference all your repository for you (as an nexus/archiva will do).
I've posted something about his on my [site](http://intelligents-ia.com/index.php/post/2011/05/24/Configuration-de-Maven).

Simply add this in your `settings.xml`:

```
<profile>
    <id>my-repository</id>
    <activation>
    <!-- here we did not activat this profile by default -->
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
    <!-- list of standard repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>javanet</id>
        <name>Repository for Maven2</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>google</id>
        <name>Google repository for Maven2</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <name>JBoss repository for Maven2</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Library Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Library Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external</url>
    </repository>
     <repository>
        <id>intelligents-ia</id>
        <name>Intelligents-ia Repository</name>
        <url>http://intelligents-ia.com/maven2</url>
     </repository>
    </repositories>
    </profile>
```

And you could build your project by adding `-Pmy-repository` on the command line:

```
mvn -Pmy-repository clean install
```

Or activate this profile by default by setting true on :

```
<activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```