# Where to actually put internal repository URL?

Tags: maven, repository, continuous-integration, maven-3, pom.xml

I see several options:

- directly in `pom.xml`
- in company super-pom
- in `settings.xml` (global or user)
- in a profile or directly (in `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`)

We want our Jenkins to push artifacts to internal repository, and developers to pull missing artifacts from there.

---

If I put the repository URL in `pom.xml`, and later the internal repository is moved to a different address, the released versions will all have a broken link.

Super-pom saves some repetition, but in a clean setup you need to somehow know where the repository is to find the parent POM — to tell you where the repository is.

---

Having the URL in settings allows one to change it without modifying the artifacts, but there are two problems:

- build will fail due to unresolved dependencies, if maven settings have no reference to the internal repo
- developers have to update their `settings.xml` files manually

---

I'm also unsure about the merits of putting repository configuration in profiles. I know it let's you easily switch the repositories on and off, but shouldn't the `-o` option and snapshot resolution settings be enough for most uses?

What about using a different repository (e.g. with instrumented classes) for integration tests?

Answer (score 1):

Configure a [single repository](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) in the users `${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml` and configure other needed repositories in your appropriate repository manager either Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva. In Jenkins there is the [Config File Provider plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) which exactly handles such situations in a very convinient way.

Comment: Can you please comment on the lack of portability of this approach? Won't this be a problem - maven docs about settings.xml is full of "don't make your build non-portable" warnings

Comment: What is non portable about this approach? Works in Windows, Linux, Mac ?

Comment: I mean non-portable in the sense described here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#ProfilePitfalls

Comment: Also see "I'd personally define the repositories required by a particular project in the project pom.xml because it keeps the build portable." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225535/where-is-the-best-place-to-specify-maven-repositories-pom-xml-or-settings-xml

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to have repeatable builds and good control over your organization internally, use a repository manager and use a mirrorOf entry in everyone’s settings.xml to point at that url.
>
> If you are exposing your source and want to make it easy for others to
>   build, then consider adding a repository entry to your POM, but don’t
>   pick a URL lightly, think long-term, and use a URL that will always be
>   under your control.

http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/